# Uncaught TypeError: j$(...).exists is not a function

Tags: jquery

```
var selector = '#Id-value_' + index;
var exist = $(selector).exists();
```

I am getting error for this piece of code.
My document ready function is

```
$(document).ready(function() {

});
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no `exists()` function in jQuery. But you can quickly write one:

```
// Add a new function to jQuery
jQuery.fn.exists = function(){ return this.length > 0; }

// Sadly, we cannot use ES6 arrow functions here. It
// would be nice if we could do this:
// jQuery.fn.exists = () => this.length > 0;

//now let's test it
if ($(selector).exists()) {
    // Do something
}
```

Or, just check for the `.length` property not being equal to `0`:

```
if ($(selector).length) {
  // will go here if at least one node matched
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Based on @K48 answer, you could also directly check if it exists by using `$(selector).length`.

```
var selector = '#Id-value_' + index;
if ($(selector).length) {
    // Do something
}
```